# Update parent pointers in a binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

The question is, given a binary tree, where each node has four pieces of data: `left`, `right` ,`data` and an empty pointer `parent`, we have to update the tree such that the `parent` pointer of each node points to its parent (the root parent pointer will naturally point to a NULL value). Now how do I do this? I tried a post-order traversal like this:

```
last = None
def mypostorder(root):
    if root:
      mypostorder(root.left)
      mypostorder(root.right)
      if last:
        last.parent = root
      last = root
```

But obviously it is not working, and I know why, after updating the `parent` pointer of a left-child, it sets it as `last`, so next time when it visits the right-child (its sibling), it sets its `parent` to the left-child. How to tweak it to get the correct result? Is it possible to do it iteratively as well, using a stack, may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it going the wrong way. I think your solution would make the parent of a node point to its child

Give this a try:

```
def myPostOrder(root, par=None):
    if root:
        root.parent = par
        myPostOrder(root.left, root)
        myPostOrder(root.right, root)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void setParent(node * ptr,node * parent_ptr)
{

if(ptr==NULL)
return;

ptr->parent=parent_ptr; //update the parent for the current node

parent_ptr=ptr; //now update the parent pointer

setParent(ptr->left,parent_ptr); //repeat the process for children

setParent(ptr->right,parent_ptr);
}
```

Initial Call : `setParent(root,NULL);`

Comment: I was just commenting that it wasn't a solution written in python (the algorithm is correct, which is why I gave you a +1). Still, this is likely homework, so I fully support the expression of the algorithm in a non-target language

Comment: I hope I didn't offend you. I never thought you sounded rude or anything. I was musing more than anything else

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, It isn't a homework question. I am not into school or college, I am a professional, and my work involves anything but these stuff. This was out of sheer academic interest, I tried to solve it, couldn't, so asked for help. Dunno how on earth can you think that it is homework. When somebody doesn't make an effort and post a question here, it is labeled homework, alright. Here I tried something, failed, hence asked. What makes you think it is homework?

Comment: @axiom, Never mind. Thanks anyway. The language is trivial, I was interested in knowing how to do it. C is fine...

Comment: @Cupidvogel: First of all, I'm sorry if I offended you somehow - that was never my intention. If you mean that homework questions are tagged with the homework tag, you are mistaken; [the tag was deprecated recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). I think it's great that you're doing this out of sheer interest and I applaud you for it. I only ever mentioned that this was likely homework because it could very well be part of a homework question - I have seen such questions here before.

Comment: No no, I wasn't offended, but I have seen some of my questions being unjustly closed or deleted just because the high-point-earners, by means of their 'experience', had a premonition that this might be a home-work question, despite showing my effort, and hence they closed it. So whenever I see someone mentioning `home-work` in their comment, I grow wary...